# QR Code Scanning in Asp.net Web application and taking picture option using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, camera, qr-code

I need to develop a web application which needs to scan the QR code and read the contents of it.

Is it possible with Asp.net Web application , the code behind used is C#.

Is it possible to take a picture and save it using c#.net in web application

Answer (score 0):

Take a picture in the browser client. Send image data to c# pages.

```
<input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

It is just a html file input,you can get the QR image data,when image received by select or camera .

```
$("#upload").on('change', function() {
    var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
    if(!file) {//undefined
        return;
    }
    if(!startLoading()) {
        return;
    }
    var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // read file as Data URL
    reader.onload = function() {
        var base64 = this.result;
        //send this base64 string to c# backend page using ajax
        ...
});
```

Then code in you c# page,get the base64 string,change to image.

```
byte[] arr2 = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(arr2))
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms2);
    bmp2.Save(filePath + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
    ...
```